# R Filter by sequence of events

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an event log data. For reproducible example, let's use the data from `eventdataR`

```
eventdataR::patients
## look at patient 1 sequence

eventdataR::patients %>% dplyr::filter(patient == '1')
# A tibble: 12 x 7
   handling      patient employee handling_id registration_ty~ time                .order
   <fct>         <chr>   <fct>    <chr>       <fct>            <dttm>               <int>
 1 Registration  1       r1       1           start            2017-01-02 11:41:53      1
 2 Triage and A~ 1       r2       501         start            2017-01-02 12:40:20      2
 3 Blood test    1       r3       1001        start            2017-01-05 08:59:04      3
 4 MRI SCAN      1       r4       1238        start            2017-01-05 21:37:12      4
 5 Discuss Resu~ 1       r6       1735        start            2017-01-07 07:57:49      5
 6 Check-out     1       r7       2230        start            2017-01-09 17:09:43      6
 7 Registration  1       r1       1           complete         2017-01-02 12:40:20      7
 8 Triage and A~ 1       r2       501         complete         2017-01-02 22:32:25      8
 9 Blood test    1       r3       1001        complete         2017-01-05 14:34:27      9
10 MRI SCAN      1       r4       1238        complete         2017-01-06 01:54:23     10
11 Discuss Resu~ 1       r6       1735        complete         2017-01-07 10:18:08     11
12 Check-out     1       r7       2230        complete         2017-01-09 19:45:45     12
```

In the above example, we can see the sequence of `handling` for patient `1` over a period of time. We can imagine that different patients would have different sequences or went through different number of sequences.

Now let's say I'm interested in a specific sequence and want to know which patients had gone through this specific sequence. How can I filter this dataset by this specific sequence so that I can get to know who these patients are?

The `filter_activity_presence` from `edeaR` library can help me with identifying the unique sequences and its frequency

```
patients %>% traces
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  trace                                               absolute_frequen~ relative_frequen~
  <chr>                                                           <int>             <dbl>
1 Registration,Triage and Assessment,X-Ray,Discuss R~               258             0.516
2 Registration,Triage and Assessment,Blood test,MRI ~               234             0.468
3 Registration,Triage and Assessment,Blood test,MRI ~                 2             0.004
4 Registration,Triage and Assessment,X-Ray                            2             0.004
5 Registration,Triage and Assessment                                  2             0.004
6 Registration,Triage and Assessment,X-Ray,Discuss R~                 1             0.002
7 Registration,Triage and Assessment,Blood test                       1             0.002
```

Let's say I'm interested in sequence from row 5, that is patients who had exclusively this sequence `Registration -> Triage -> Assessment`, there are 2 patients who had this sequence.

It seems the library that doesn't provide ready made function to extract this. At least from this doc page, https://www.bupar.net/subsetting.html#trace_length, it's not available.

Basically, given an exhaustive list of sequence, return all the patients who had gone through exactly this sequence.

In fact, if I can rebuild the `trace` and map it back to the original dataset, that should allow for a simple `dplyr::filter`. But this may not be ideal as well in the case if I'm interested in open ended sequence, for example, find all patients who started with `Registration -> Triage` and can be followed by any sequence.

Here's my long-winded attempt

```
# get trace for each patient
patient_trace <- as_tibble(patients) %>% group_by(patient) %>% dplyr::filter(registration_type == 'complete') %>%
  summarise(trace = paste(handling, collapse = ","), n = n())

# identify the sequence trace of interest
trace_summary <- patients %>% traces

# here we want to see patients who had the sequence from row 5
res <- patients %>%
  dplyr::filter(patient %in% c(patient_trace %>% dplyr::filter(trace %in% trace_summary$trace[5]) %>% .$patient)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(registration_type == 'complete') %>% 
  arrange(patient, time)

# A tibble: 4 x 7
  handling       patient employee handling_id registration_ty~ time                .order
  <fct>          <chr>   <fct>    <chr>       <fct>            <dttm>               <int>
1 Registration   499     r1       499         complete         2018-05-01 22:57:38      1
2 Triage and As~ 499     r2       999         complete         2018-05-04 23:53:27      3
3 Registration   500     r1       500         complete         2018-05-02 01:28:23      2
4 Triage and As~ 500     r2       1000        complete         2018-05-05 07:16:02      4
```

Comment: What does `traces` actually show? `patients %>% group_by(patient) %>%  summarise(trace = paste(handling, collapse = ","))` shows that `'Registration,Triage and Assessment'` are part of the first 10 patients. Why does traces function return 2?

Comment: @RonakShah, the traces function return 2 because it looks at the `exact sequence`. I've added the results where there are 2 patients who had `exactly only` `Registration` followed by `Triage and Assessment`. You're right in the sense that if you want to filter by any patient who had gone through these 2 sequences but may be followed by any other sequence. But I may also want to know who had exactly these 2 sequences and nothing else right after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` them with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
req_sequence <- c('Registration', 'Triage and Assessment')

eventdataR::patients %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  filter(all(handling == req_sequence)) %>%
  filter(registration_type == 'complete') %>%
  ungroup

#   handling              patient employee handling_id registration_type time                .order
#  <fct>                 <chr>   <fct>    <chr>       <fct>             <dttm>               <int>
#1 Registration          499     r1       499         complete          2018-05-01 22:57:38   3220
#2 Registration          500     r1       500         complete          2018-05-02 01:28:23   3221
#3 Triage and Assessment 499     r2       999         complete          2018-05-04 23:53:27   3720
#4 Triage and Assessment 500     r2       1000        complete          2018-05-05 07:16:02   3721
```

---

For this case to be sure of the output and to avoid any recycling effect we can `filter` `registration_type == 'complete'` first and also add another check of `length(req_sequence)` equal to number of rows for the patient id.

```
eventdataR::patients %>%
  filter(registration_type == 'complete') %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  filter(length(req_sequence) == n() && all(handling == req_sequence)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: I think this will assume that `Registration` and `Triage and Assessment` are always in that order. If there're patients who somehow had `Triage and Assessment` followed by `Registration`, this solution will also return these patients which should not be the case. It's important that the order of the sequence is followed

Comment: @AfiqJohari No, this will not return patients who have `'Triage and Assessment'` followed by `'Registration'`, that is why I am using `==` and not `%in%`.  This returns only those rows in the same order as specified in `req_sequence`.

Comment: I tried reversing the time, but I still get the reversed sequence. `patients_rv <- as_tibble(eventdataR::patients) %>%
  filter(registration_type == 'complete') %>%
  group_by(patient) 
###
patients_rv$time <- rev(patients_rv$time) # reverse time
###
patients_rv %>%
  filter(length(req_sequence) == n() && all(handling == req_sequence)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  arrange(patient, time)`

Comment: If you look at the data (`patients_rv %>%  filter(patient %in% 499:500)`) it is still in the same order as `req_sequence`. Try these two commands to see the difference - `patients_rv %>%  
  filter(patient %in% 499:500) %>% arrange(patient, handling) %>% group_by(patient) %>% filter(length(req_sequence) == n() && all(handling == req_sequence))` and `patients_rv %>%  filter(patient %in% 499:500) %>% arrange(patient, desc(handling)) %>% group_by(patient) %>% filter(length(req_sequence) == n() && all(handling == req_sequence))`. The difference is only `arrange` (`desc(handling)`).

Comment: ah my bad, time was reversed but not handling. Got it. Thanks again!